# Android unable to run unit test

Tags: android, android-build, android-testing

I'm trying to script out unit test for Android on a Mac. I'm able to get it running via Eclipse, but need to be able to automate everything.

To create the project I'm running

```
~/workspace$ android create test-project -m ../ -p ROAMpayX/tests -n ROAMPayTest
```

I'm trying to run the following command

```
adb shell am instrument -w com.roamdata.roampayx/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

and keep getting the following error (which my AndroidManifest.xml in my test folder gave me)

> INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
>   INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.roamdata.roampayx/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
>   android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: com.roamdata.roampayx/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
>   INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
>       at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:616)
>       at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:118)
>       at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:81)
>       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Clearly this is some kind of pathing issue. Is there something that I am missing? I've tried running the command from both the mainproject folder and the testsproject folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that the problem ended up being how my packages were subclassed. I was giving it the root package, but the Activity I was testing was another step step deeper and the auto create did not account for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.roamdata.roampayx/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}

It says that can not find android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner inside com.roamdata.roampayx

and why not use ant http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html for test running ? Is it specific purpose?

If you go with ant, you can pick up some ideas or ant tasks from https://github.com/inazaruk/robomorphine-testrunner/wiki , but it may be overhead for now.

Comment: Sure. I suppose I can use ant, I'm not really tied down to any command  line specific tool, yet. I read that page (several times because I've been there before) I used the example they gave, but they don't seem to give an example of how to use ant. The wiki you sent seemed like a little overkill for my purposes. Any further suggests?

Comment: yes wiki is overkill, for official you have update your project with "android" tool and call "ant run-tests" http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html#RunTestsAnt

Comment: Closer. I performed those steps and now I get a target "run-tests" does not exist in the project. Gonna upvote for your help so far.

Comment: Don't really know what happened, but I was playing with ant and this issue seemed to fix itself. Note that I'm using everything as started in the question. Make sure to double check package names in your tests.  Also note that there is currently an error with ant run-tests http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32598

Answer (score 3):

Did you buid and install the test project before running the `adb` command? 
You could do it easily with ant with the following command:

```
ant debug install test
```